# Error with php switch function

Tags: php, switch-statement

I´ve got the following code and when I paste the code to my page, I get a white page, can you guys help me?

### PHP

```
<?php $strRendersettings = ($this->settings)? 'settings' : 'view'; ?><?php if (count($this->data)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
        {
            case ("www.domain.de"):
            foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                <li class="new_doc_home"><a href=""; ?>" ><strong><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:</strong><br>
                    <p><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?></p></a>
                </li>
        <?php
            break;
           
            case ("www.domain.com"):
                foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                    <li class="new_doc_home"><a href=""; ?>" ><strong><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:</strong><br>
                        <p><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?></p></a>
                    </li>
        <?php
                    break;

            case ("www.domain.fr"):
                foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                    <li class="new_doc_home"><a href=""; ?>" ><strong><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:</strong><br>
                            <p><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?></p></a>
                    </li>
         <?php
            break;
                }
            ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I need the code because of some different top level domains.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The porblem is that you never end you foreach loops.

You should end each `foreach:` loop with `endforeach;`. Now you have 3 loops and only one closing `endforeach;`

For example this code works without a problem:

```
<?php
$array = [1=>2, 3=> 4];

$array2 = [5=>6,7=>8];

foreach ($array as $k => $v):

    foreach ($array2 as $i => $j):
         echo $i.' '.$j."<br />";

    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

while the following doesn't:

```
<?php

$array = [1=>2, 3=> 4];

$array2 = [5=>6,7=>8];

foreach ($array as $k => $v):

    foreach ($array2 as $i => $j):
         echo $i.' '.$j."<br />";

    //endforeach;
endforeach;
```

I advice you also to add at the beginning of your PHP file:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

to have all warnings and error displayed. Of course on production you should disable error reporting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're breaking the foreach loop with the break of the switch. You should end the foreach inside each case of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

See you PHP error log for error messages. When there is a parse error, the page is shown blank, and the error message goes to the PHP error log.

In your code, `<?php endforeach; ?>` appears to be outside the switch. I guess each `foreach` should have its own `endforeach` before the `switch`'s `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are doing the exact same thing for each of the three scenarios. I would alter my code to this:

```
<?php $strRendersettings = ($this->settings)? 'settings' : 'view'; ?>
<?php if (count($this->data)): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    {
        case "www.domain.de":
        case "www.domain.com":
        case "www.domain.fr":
            foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                <li class="new_doc_home">
                    <a href="">
                        <strong>
                            <?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:
                        </strong><br>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?>
                        </p>
                     </a>
                </li>        
            <?php 
            endforeach; 
            break; 
    }?>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `endforeach` statement before every `break` statement. Add that and your error will get sloved.
Hope this help :)